# Removing complex numbers from a set

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, filtering

I have the following list:

```
{{-1628.11740799393 - 557.339672450634 I}, {-1628.11740799393 + 557.339672450634 I},
 {-920.324284271774 - 1508.13304084624 I}, {-920.324284271774 + 1508.13304084624 I},
 {2107.28351459532}, {2145.53211042304}, {2207.19944421678}, {2289.69932193979},
 {2318.0488541237 - 13.4030555095579 I}, {2318.0488541237 + 13.4030555095579 I}}
```

I would like to remove the complex numbers (Real & Imaginary parts) from this set and keep the real sets only which are 4 subsets in this case. I really appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alist = {-1628.12 - 557.34 I, -1628.12 + 557.34 I, -920.324 - 
   1508.13 I, -920.324 + 1508.13 I, 2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7, 
  2318.05 - 13.4031 I, 2318.05 + 13.4031 I}

Cases[alist, Except@_Complex]
```

> {2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7}

Answer (score 4):

Try `Select`

```
list={-1628.12 - 557.34 I, -1628.12 + 557.34 I, -920.324 - 1508.13 I, -920.324 + 1508.13 I, 2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7,2318.05 - 13.4031 I, 2318.05 + 13.4031 I}

Select[list, Im[#] == 0 &]
(*{2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7}*)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much @Ulrich Neumann...

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Try `DeleteCases`:

```
list={-1628.12 - 557.34 I, -1628.12 + 557.34 I, -920.324 - 1508.13 I,-920.324 + 1508.13 I, 2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7,2318.05 - 13.4031 I, 2318.05 + 13.4031 I}
DeleteCases[list, _Complex]
(*{2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

With appended `Integer` and `Rational`:

```
list =
  {-1628.12 - 557.34 I, -1628.12 + 557.34 I, -920.324 - 
    1508.13 I, -920.324 + 1508.13 I, 2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7,
    2318.05 - 13.4031 I, 2318.05 + 13.4031 I, 99, 3/4};

Pick[list, RealValuedNumberQ /@ list]
```

{2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7, 99, 3/4}

Compare to

```
Pick[list, MatchQ[_Real] /@ list]
```

{2107.28, 2145.53, 2207.2, 2289.7}

`RealValuedNumberQ` came with `V 13.3`