# Why is ComplexQ not available?

Tags: functions, complex, language-design

For `` names = Names["System`*"]; `` executing the following returns 200 hits.

```
(StringCases[names, ___ ~~ "Q" ~~ EndOfString] // 
   Flatten /. {} -> Nothing) // Length
```

> (*200) A sample is presented below.
>
> ```
> {"AcyclicGraphQ", "AlgebraicIntegerQ", "AlgebraicUnitQ", \
> "AntihermitianMatrixQ", "AntisymmetricMatrixQ", "ArgumentCountQ", \
> "ArrayQ", "AskedQ", "AssociationQ", "AtomQ", "AudioInstanceQ", \
> "AudioQ", "BinaryImageQ", "BioSequenceQ", "BipartiteGraphQ", "BondQ", \
> "BooleanQ", "BoundaryMeshRegionQ", "BoundedRegionQ", "BusinessDayQ"}
> ```

#### Question

For what reason is `ComplexQ` missing from this list of queries?

Comment: most likely because one can use `Element[x,Complexes]`

Comment: Also, isn't `NumericQ` equivalent to your hypothetical `ComplexQ`?

Comment: What would you like it to do? What answer should it give for real numbers?

Comment: Notice that there's also no `RealQ`, but `MatchQ[RandomComplex[], _Complex]` is True, `MatchQ[RandomReal[], _Complex]` is False, `MatchQ[RandomComplex[], _Real]` is False, and `MatchQ[RandomReal[], _Real]` is True.

Comment: May I ask why one of these definitions above have not been conveniently rolled up into ComplexQ?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/254085/removing-complex-numbers-from-a-set/254090#254090 -- while responding to this question, the thought came to my  mind. All Reals can be considered Complex numbers too with zero imaginary part. I thought there would be a ComplexQ available, but there wasn't, and hence the question.

Comment: In a purely mathematical sense, reals are a subset of complexes, and integers are a subset of reals. However, in Mathematica, a number is complex only its `Head` is `Complex`; real only if its  `Head` is `Real`; and integer only if its `Head` is `Integer`: evaluate `Head /@ {1. + I, 1., 1}`

Comment: What are you, in fact, trying to do with the test function `ComplexQ`? If you merely want to do argument checking in a defined function, you may simply use the pattern `z_Complex`, meaning that `z` must have head `Complex`.

Comment: @murray : If I understand it correctly: In Mma, an integer is something without a decimal point, a real is something with a decimal point and a Complex number is something with a non-zero imaginary part along with an optional Real | Integer part. An implementation could be:  `ComplexQ[x_]:=If[Head[x]===Complex, True, False]` ?

Comment: @Syed Some undocumented ones are in ```Names["Developer`*"]```

Comment: @Syed note that `If[Head[x]===Complex, True, False]` is better written as (and is equivalent to) `MatchQ[x, _Complex]`; also, note that e.g. `Exp[I Pi/3]` is not considered complex under this definition, as it does not expand into real/imaginary parts automatically, and so its head is `Power`. Yet, `Element[Exp[I Pi/3], Complexes]` evaluates to `True`. This should help you narrow down what you want: something that picks out an implementation form, or something that assesses a "mathematical property".

Comment: Thanks @thorimur. I am learning new stuff with every comment.